# Line integral of the unit circle

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $C$ be the bottom half of the unit circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$ traversed
>   counter clockwise. Calculate $\int_{C} \vec{F}\cdot\, d\vec{r}$.

What is the question asking and why is a parameterization of $C$, $r(t) = (\cos{t}, \sin{t})$ where $\pi \le t \le 2\pi$. Is it because if we start from $(1,0)$ and move around the circle counter clockwise, the point $(-1, 0)$ corresponds to $\pi$ (half a circle) and arriving back $(1,0)$ corresponds to $2\pi$ (full circle)?

I'm asking: what do they mean by traversed counter clockwise? Where does $\pi \le t \le 2\pi$ come from?

Comment: Yes, the $\pi \le t \le 2 \pi$ is due to the reason you stated. We're starting at the point $(-1,0)$, which is $\pi$ radians from $(1,0)$, and ending at $(1,0)$, which is at $2 \pi$ radians from $(1,0)$ (after traversing counter clockwise). Traversed counter clockwise just means we travel in a certain orientation; our path along the unit circle is _counter clockwise_ (i.e from the point $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0)$ to $(0,-1)$ to $(1,0)$ again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Traversed counter clockwise" means we go in the opposite direction to the direction followed by the hands of an analogue clock. That is, we go from 9 o'clock to 8 o'clock...to 4 o'clock to 3 o'clock.

Suppose we want walk along such a circle according to  the rule that our position must at all times $t$ be $(\cos t,\sin t)$. If we start when $t=\pi$,  we start at the position with coordinates $(\cos \pi,\sin \pi)=(-1,0)$. When $t$ has changed to $t=3\pi/2=\pi+\pi/2$, we have changed our position to $(\cos 3\pi/2,\sin 3\pi/2)=(0,-1)$. 
When $t=2\pi$, we are at $(\cos 2\pi,\sin 2\pi)=(1,0)$, etc. Thus as $t$ changes from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, our position on the circle changes accordingly.